# can't get data-labels in highcharts-export-server on live server

Tags: node.js, highcharts

1. i am using **highcharts-export-server** for export charts and send it to Email in PDF format
2. while i am trying to export that in localy it was working fine, but on live server when i am trying to export all the **charts data-labels disappear**.

   > this is the image from which was exporting from live server.

[image]

> and here is the image which was exporting locally.

[image]

> Here is my Code

```
exports.getPieChartImg = (seriesData, xOrLength, innersize, showLegend, width, height) => {
var chartOpts = {
    chart: {
        type: 'pie',
        width: width,
        height: height,
    },
    plotOptions: {
        pie: {
            innerSize: innersize || 80,
            depth: 25,
            allowPointSelect: true,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: false,
                format: '<b>{point.name}</b>: {point.percentage:.2f} %'
            },
            showInLegend: showLegend || false,
        },
        series: {
            stacking: 'normal',
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true,
                color: '#6f6f6f',
                format: '{point.percentage:.2f}',
                crop: false,
                overflow: "none",
            },
            pointWidth: 30,
        }
    },
    legend: {
        labelFormat: '<b>{name}</b> ({percentage:.2f})%',
        useHTML: true,
    },
    series: [{
        data: seriesData
    }]
};

var exportSettings = generateExportSettings(chartOpts, 'Pie');
return generateBase64Chart(exportSettings)
}

function generateExportSettings(chartOpts, constr) {
return {
    // b64: true,
    instr: JSON.stringify(chartOpts),
    noDownload: true,
    constr,
    globalOptions: {
        colors: ['#3BB9DA', '#0F89A8', '#0B8F8B', '#1DB1AD', '#68E3DF', '#FFB469', '#F58B1F', '#D16900', '#FC3C3C', '#FF6666', '#FC8D8D', '#FCC0C0'],
        lang: {
            thousandsSep: ','
        }
    },
    scale: false,
    styledMode: false,
    type: "image/png",
    width: false,
};
 }

function generateBase64Chart(exportSettings) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    highchartsExporter.export(exportSettings, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            return reject({
                code: '1',
                err,
                msg: 'Error in stock chart',
                exportSettings
            })
        }
        return resolve({
            code: '0',
            msg: 'success',
            data: 'data:image/png;base64,' + res.data,
        })
    });
})
}
```

Comment: Could you try to provide me with your chart configuration? It would be great to see that, because it can be caused by `useHTML` parameter.

Comment: @daniel_s i edited my Question.

Comment: Thank you for your edit, but still I don't know what happening with your code. I'm not so sure that the chart configuration can causing something like that, because exporting is working well on on it. here is the example: https://jsfiddle.net/L4e7gkxz/
I need to know, what are the `generateExportSettings` and `generateBase64Chart` functions

Comment: @daniel_s i added that Two function also, please see the Question.

Comment: Are you sure that you're using the same versions on both locations? Which live server are you using exactly? You have your own instance of `node-export-server` or you're trying to export it on official highcharts export server?

Comment: @daniel_s this is my package dependencies => "highcharts-export-server": "https://github.com/dhyey35/node-export-server.git" in package.json on both location, do you think is there any issue with it?

Comment: Unfortunately, you're using the `highcharts-export-server` package, which is deprecated, and unsupported now. Please try to use our new `node-export-server` package in order to make your app working with new versions of Highcharts. Here is more info about it: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/export-module/258

Comment: @daniel_s i am using https://github.com/dhyey35/node-export-server, which is the **node-export-server**

Comment: Thank you for explanation. I was confused a bit because you called `highcharts-export-server` the `node-export-server`, but those are two different packages. Anyway, the problem looks like related with machines setups (operating systems). I think, that's the time to open a new issue on `node-export-server` GitHub repository, and there you need to describe your problem as precisely as here. Additionally, please specify the setups of your machines (local and server) there.

Comment: Also, make sure you have the correct fonts on the server to match your chart fonts used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. remove **node_module** and reInstall it again.
2. and if not installed libfontconfig then install **'sudo apt-get install libfontconfig'**